# Filter data based on result set of group and count

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by, count

I have the following table

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A1      B1      C1
A1      B1      C2
A1      B2      C1
A1      B2      C2
A1      B2      C3
A2      B1      C1
A2      B1      C2
A2      B2      C1
A2      B2      C2
```

From this table I want all the unique records from Col1 where for the combination of col1 and col2 there's a different count for the same value in Col1. The only possible answer is A1 in the table above.

The following query gives me the count of each col1 and col2.

```
select col1, col2, count(*) from table
group by col1, col2;

Col1    Col2    Count
A1      B1      2
A1      B2      3
A2      B1      2
A2      B2      2
```

From the above query I can see that A1 has two records with a different count. How do I return A1 in a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another level of aggregation:

```
select col1
from (select col1, col2, count(*) as cnt
      from table
      group by col1, col2
     ) t
group by col1
having min(cnt) <> max(cnt);
```

Comment: That's true. I added that because it was related to what I needed. I'll remove it from the question so it's clear for others. Can you modify the answer too so I can accept it.